# jQuery client event not working in on Safari 5.1

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile, safari

I am working a mobile website, using jQuery Mobile. Safari browser (5.1) not recognzing jQuery click event - like ("#button1").click (function (){ ...... });

Any idea?

Code Snippets:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});

<form id="loginForm" class="validate" action=""  method="get">
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" /> </form>
```

Comment: Hiya man, I am on safari and click event is very well recognized Hope you are sourcing Jquery library in your code, cheers

Comment: Did you forget the '$' in front, or did you just omit that in the post?

Comment: sorry copy/paste error. $ is there.

Comment: added code snippets... works in Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#submit").on("click", function () {
      alert("hello");
});
```

Please refer to

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[jQuery Mobile Event](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `click` event is not always fired in some mobile browsers, so you may also have to bind to the `tap` event, like this:

```
$("#submit").bind("click tap", function () {
      alert("hello");
});
```

More information on jQuery Mobile events here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Comment: if you're using jquery 1.7 onwards, please consider changing to `.on()`
http://api.jquery.com/on/